# Remove automatic spacing/line breaks between html elements?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

This should be fairly simple, but after trying a lot of solutions from Google and other Stack Overflow questions I still haven't found a solution. I have a html.erb partial in a rails project:

```
<div class="resource-body">
  <div class="arrow-up"></div>
  <h4><a href="<%= resource.url %>"><%= resource.title %></a></h4>
  <div class="resource-section-id">
    <span hidden><%=resource.section_id%></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
.resource-body{
  padding-left: 20vw;
  margin: 0;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

The arrow appears above the URL. I'm trying to get the arrow to be immediately to the left of the link. I've tried the usual suspects like display: inline, etc. but no dice. Any ideas?

Comment: tried floating them left?

Comment: Try using `inline-table` for both the `.arrow-up` and the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have modified the css and added two properties in .arrow-up class

```
  float: left;
  padding-top: 6px;
```

Here is the [link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmTZ2/)

Comment: You can add reduce padding to move the position of arrow.

Comment: Props for balancing aesthetic without hard-coding everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    .arrow-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
   margin: 0;
   border-bottom: 5px solid black;
position: relative;
top: 33px;
  left: -18px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it easy!!!!!

just add this rules to your css:

```
h4 a {float:left;}
```

Enjoy it!!!